# How do I refresh my Owned Games and Wishlist?

Tags: gog-galaxy-2.0

I bought a new game a few hours ago on another device, then woke my GOG Galaxy computer which had GOG Galaxy running when it fully woke back up.

But GOG Galaxy is running on old data. The Wishlist is saying 4 items when it should be 3 now, and my new game isn't in the Owned Games list.

Can I refresh the data without shutting down the window / program and restarting it?